# How to Sent Auth0 Access Token from Flutter to Node Js Through Headers

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class ApiProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Future sentToken(Map<String, String> body) async {
    final Uri restApiUrl = Uri.parse("https://localhost:3000/dummy/");

    http.Response response = await http.post(
      restApiUrl,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': "Bearer: ${AuthService.instance.auth0AccessToken}"
      },
      body: jsonEncode(body),
    );
    return response.body;
  }
}
```

This Function Should to Called While logging to the Auth0 Account are Where to Call this Function to sent Header from flutter to node js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify, I believe what you want to do is

- log in with Auth0 and get accessToken
- Have a backed with NodJS where it validates Auth0AccessToken and authenticated and authorized user
- You need to call the NodeJS backend by passing the headers.

Therefore, once you parsed the Auth0 result after login

```
   auth0AccessToken = result.accessToken;
```

then you can call your NodeJS API by passing the `Authorization` header as you did in the example above however, you have a mistake

```dart
class ApiProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Future sentToken(Map<String, String> body) async {
    final Uri restApiUrl = Uri.parse("https://localhost:3000/dummy/");
 
    http.Response response = await http.post(
      restApiUrl,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': "Bearer ${AuthService.instance.auth0AccessToken}"
      },
      body: jsonEncode(body),
    );
    return response.body;
  }
}
```

It does not need to be a post method if you have a GET method, it should also be fine to send tokens. So your nodeJS can parse it properly.

If you just need to call your API right after login, you can actually do that exactly when you get the `result` from the `auth0` when you want to store your tokens securely in flutter for example:

```dart
// /lib/services/auth_service.dart

  login() async {
      final authorizationTokenRequest = AuthorizationTokenRequest(
        AUTH0_CLIENT_ID, AUTH0_REDIRECT_URI,
        issuer: AUTH0_ISSUER,
        scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'offline_access', 'email'],
      );
      final AuthorizationTokenResponse? result =
          await appAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(
        authorizationTokenRequest,
      );
      print(result);
     // you can call it here 
  Future sentToken(Map<String, String> body) async {
    final Uri restApiUrl = Uri.parse("https://localhost:3000/dummy/");

    http.Response response = await http.post(
      restApiUrl,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': "Bearer: ${AuthService.instance.auth0AccessToken}"
      },
      body: jsonEncode(body),
    );
    return response.body;
  }

  }
```

I have written an extensive article about Auth0 and Flutter and you can find it here

- Part 1:
  https://auth0.com/blog/flutter-authentication-authorization-with-auth0-part-1-adding-authentication-to-an-app/
- Part 2:
  https://auth0.com/blog/flutter-authentication-authorization-with-auth0-part-2-refresh-tokens-social-logins-more/
- Part 3:
  https://auth0.com/blog/flutter-authentication-authorization-with-auth0-part-3-adding-real-time-chat-to-the-app/
- Part 4:
  https://auth0.com/blog/flutter-authentication-authorization-with-auth0-part-4-roles-permissions/

Comment: I read this Article and Implemented the Authentication but i am facing a Issue on ReLogin Once I hit logout the application logged out and i comes to login screen but when i hit again login its throw a error kindly call a method but in Ontap i have called the method what kind of issue is this ?

Comment: mm that's strange, it's hard to debug if you don't show me what you have done, but I can imagine that probably you have some values in your OnTap where after logout it will become NULL and therefore, you cannot call or get that value. is that the case? can you possibly send your error? maybe in another issue.

Comment: Yes its Showing like that after I logged out and try to login again its show try to call a Method Call() like this

Comment: do you have stack trace?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/tgfkiPDj   This is AuthServer Class File

Comment: https://pastebin.com/yRtNy6Tt This is AppState to Navigate to Next Screen after Login

Comment: but where does the error happen? which line? do you have stacktrace?

Comment: No I have to Check that its on Office System Let me Initimate Once i Reach and I think there is one more the loginAction() is Called inside onPress but it show error like this on Top of Stful Widget I have Declared                                                                                                                                                                                                                    The method 'loginAction' isn't defined for the type '_LoginScreenState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'loginAction'.

Comment: when i called the loginAction like this its Working  widget.loginAction(); what kind of issue is this

Comment: I guess, it's because you are passing LoginActionto a stateful widget `LoginScreen(loginAction, errorMessage),` and therefore in the `state` class of the widget, you must call `widget.loginAction` which is a parameter to the constructor. that's why.

Comment: Uh Okie let me see that and also I will update the issue regarding relogin as soon as possible

Comment: I think you should post another question if you cannot figure it out.